# Floating action button press show circluar progress bar above the floating action button with time indication

Tags: dart, flutter

I am working to record a audio for 30 sec when the floating action is pressed a circular button with 30 sec timer has to shown above the floating action button when i press the button again the timer should stop and when i start again the timer should continue from its previous stopping place.

Comment: Give me some solution to solve this issue

Comment: You might not be getting audio to text conversion response because google require's specific encoding of audio file which you can find on the following link
[speech-to-text/docs/encoding](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/encoding)